# Rename beginning of file name using specific text in the file itself

Tags: text-processing, sed, rename

I have many files in directory (`file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, ...)

Every files contains bunch of lines. One of the line is specific text `thetext` followed by random number just like `thetext56`, `thetext21`, etc.

I want to rename beginning of the file name using specific text in the file itself. So, `file1.txt` will be `thetextXXfile1.txt`, `file2.txt` will be `thetextXXfile2.txt`, and so on.

Simple rename command to add `addtext` on the beginning is

```
rename 's?^?addtext?' *.html
```

while getting that specific text in the files is

```
sed '/thetext/!d' *.html
```

but I have no idea how to combine both of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that `grep` is a better tool for `sed` when what you want to do is read one line out of a file based on a match. You are welcome to substitute your `sed` in the loop structure below. Note that I also used the `-m 1` option so that grep only bothers looking as far as the first match:

```
for file in *.html; do
   text="$(grep -m 1 "thetext" "$file")"
   rename "s?$text?" "$file"
done
```